# Отделить от строки что в символе "

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Привет.

```
    <div class="name">
<?$deli = chr(34);
$item = explode($deli, $arItem["NAME"])?>
<a href="<?=$arItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']?>"><?print_r($item)?></a>
</div>
```

Название, к примеру, Что-то "Что-то в двойных кавычках". Не разбивает и всё.

Comment: Что надо разделить то, непонятно. Какой текст содержится в переменной `$arItem["NAME"]`? Что за символ `chr(34)` и зачем его надо писать через функцию `chr()`?

P.S.: 

>Что та "Что та

Правильно писать "`Что-то "Что-то`"

Comment: $arItem["NAme"] к примеру = Ночная сорочка "Вологда". Почему через chr, потому что он не принимает explode(""", $arItem["NAme"]). Мне необходимо текст в " " отделить от строки. Пробовал регуляркой, ещё больше ереси наворочал.

Comment: @Роман20, чтобы использовать кавычку в строке, нужно либо взять строку в других кавычках (строки могут быть записаны как в апострофах/одиночных кавычках, так и в обычных двойных), либо заэкранировать кавычку обратным слэшем.

    'abcd"dbca' === "abcd\"dbca"

Answer (score 1):

Бред ваши регулярки, есть очень удобный метод split.

```
Пример #2 Пример использования split()
```

Распознаем дату, отформатированную с использованием слешей, точек или дефисов:

```
<?php
// Разделителями могут быть слеши, точки или дефисы
$date = "04/30/1973";
list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $date);
echo "Месяц: $month; День: $day; Год: $year<br />\n";
?>
```

Вот [ссылочка](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.split.php) с примерами, думаю, поймете.

Comment: > Бред ваши регулярки

@djbolya, а разве у вас первым параметром в split() не регулярка? ))

Answer (score 0):

[@Роман20](/users/16997/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD20) - Вы пробовали двойную кавычку поставить в одинарные, ну или экранировать?

Вообще, explode здесь не самый лучший вариант решения, я бы порекомендовал использовать регулярные выражения.

Код на [`Ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/NI6wmi)